# Sitecore Coveo Free Version Exclusion rule not working

Tags: search, indexing, sitecore, sitecore8, coveo

I have been using Coveo7 free version with Sitecore 8.1 update 1,
Configured the coveo to index all the content items under a path. 404 page is also under the same path, so tried to exclude the item by adding an exclusion rule in indexed documents. I checked in filters also, i'm able to see that exclusion rule is added to the list. But the same document is still coming up in search results.

I have tried the following options.
1. Rebuild index.
2. Full refresh of the index.
3. Delete the complete source and rebuild the index from sitecore.

I'm using Coveo admin credentials to login the index browser, but i'm not able to see the options to remove the corresponding indexed item.

Below are the screenshots.
[unable to delete from index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2yOb.png)

[Exclusion rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykz0L.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With Coveo for Sitecore, you cannot use the CES7 "Add an Exclusion Filter" feature from the Index Browser. You need to filter the items to be indexed from the Coveo for Sitecore configuration files inside Sitecore. There two ways to do it:

- Via [ExcludeTemplate/AddExcludedTemplate](https://developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Customizing+the+Indexing+Parameters)
- Via [inbound filters](https://developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Excluding+Sitecore+Items+From+Your+Index)

A rebuild of the indexes in Sitecore is needed after you modify those configurations.

Note: Rebuilding/refreshing the Sitecore sources from CES7 have no impact as it only closes and re-open the communication to RabbitMQ to listen for messages. It doesn't instruct Sitecore to index items. All the rebuild operations must be done in Sitecore.